# Interesting widget conundrum

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I have a widget that mostly does what I want it to (Starts an intent) but I'm wondering how I can squeeze multiple intents into one widget provider.

I have tried all the usual means of getting this done:

- Using more then one intent
- using a second widget with the same theme settings
  and a few others here and there that were ultimately failures.

Generic code:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, myClass.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startIntent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.MyWidget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.startBtn, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }       
}
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to get more then one button on the widget. Since its set up for three and I know one of them works so I'm 1/3 the way there.

here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startBtn"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="First Menu Item"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startBtn2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Second menu item" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startBtn3"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Third menu item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the contents of the xml file R.layout.MyWidget

Comment: @edthethird nice Bebop reference and the XML has been added.

Comment: haha it's actually my name, didn't realize it was a Bebop reference... nice coincidence though!

Comment: @edthethird I'm sure you know the name then! xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you almost got it!  The idea is to create 3 different `PendingIntents` and 3 different `Intents`, and then call `setOnClickPendingIntent` 3 times.  One for each action and button.  Here is an example, assuming the three activities are myClass, myClass2, and myClass3.  With the below code, each button will fire off a different intent.

```
for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, myClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startIntent, 0);

    Intent startIntent2 = new Intent(context, myClass2.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startIntent2, 0);

    Intent startIntent3 = new Intent(context, myClass3.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startIntent3, 0);

    // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.MyWidget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.startBtn, pendingIntent);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.startBtn2, pendingIntent2);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.startBtn3, pendingIntent3);


    // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```